# Why do I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS here and how can I make it work?

Tags: c++, string, strtok

I'm trying to make my code be able to separate [a file](http://drop.io/xodrl0f) into a customer database (it's delimited by many spaces and not tabs). I try to use strtok, but I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Here is my main.cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "Cust.h"
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    Cust customers[500];
 int idx = 0;
 string tmpString = "";
 string tmpAcctFN = "";
 string tmpAcctLN = "";
 ifstream input("P3_custData.txt");
 while (!input.eof()){
  getline(input,tmpString);
  tmpString.insert(0,"");
  customers[idx].setAcctNum(atoi(strtok((char *)tmpString.c_str()," ")));
  customers[idx].setAcctFN(strtok(NULL," "));
  customers[idx].setAcctLN(strtok(NULL," "));
  //customers[idx].setCurrBalance(atof(strtok((char *) tmpString.c_str()," ")));
 }
 cout << "return 0;";
    return 0;
}
```

I still get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS after making changes based on the comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "Cust.h"
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    Cust customers[500];
    int idx = 0;
    string tmpString = "";
    string tmpAcctFN = "";
    string tmpAcctLN = "";
    char * s;
    ifstream input("P3_custData.txt");
    while (!input.eof()){
        getline(input,tmpString);
        s = strdup (tmpString.c_str());
        customers[idx].setAcctNum(atoi(strtok(s," ")));
        customers[idx].setAcctFN(strtok(NULL," "));
        customers[idx].setAcctLN(strtok(NULL," "));
        //customers[idx].setCurrBalance(atof(strtok((char *) tmpString.c_str()," ")));
    }
    cout << "return 0;";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Anthony, I think your problem is a malformed input line - see my update on how to detect and solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is illegal to attempt to modify the string returned by `std::string::c_str()` method. `strtok` will make such an attempt (the fact that you had to cast away the constness of the returned string is a dead giveaway). In other words, you can't use `strtok` on the result of `std::string::c_str()`.

Either get rid of `strtok` (better), or create a standalone modifiable copy of the string and use `strtok` on it (worse).

Comment: How would I do that considering the fact that I'm in a while loop?

Comment: If you ever find yourself casting away the `const`-ness of a variable, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: What has the loop to with it? To get rid of `strtok()` options include `string::find()` or something like boosts string algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The `c_str` method will return a pointer to `const` data. One approach is to replace:

```
customers[idx].setAcctNum(atoi(strtok((char *)tmpString.c_str()," ")));
customers[idx].setAcctFN(strtok(NULL," "));
customers[idx].setAcctLN(strtok(NULL," "));
```

with:

```
char *s = strdup (tmpString.c_str());
// check if s is NULL
customers[idx].setAcctNum(atoi(strtok(s," ")));
customers[idx].setAcctFN(strtok(NULL," "));
customers[idx].setAcctLN(strtok(NULL," "));
free (s);
```

This gives you a duplicate *writeable* string that you can run `strtok` on.

I'm not usually a *big* fan of using old-style C stuff in C++ code but I'm also pragmatic in getting code running. There may well be a more "C++" way of doing things.

And, if your implementation doesn't have a `strdup` (I don't think it's part of the standard):

```
char *strdup (const char *s) {
    char *d = (char *)(malloc (strlen (s) + 1));
    if (d == NULL) return NULL;
    strcpy (d,s);
    return d;
}
```

*Update:*

Anthony, based on the updates to your question, if you're getting an error still then it's probably because the string is not what you expect. Come to think of it, you should *not* get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` from writing to the result of a `c_str` since the memory is technically not read-only. `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` should only occur if you try to write to read-only memory (or outside your address space). As one commenter has pointed out, `c_str` *may* return a pointer to read-only memory for certain simple cases but that's unlikely to be the case here if your file has complex lines.

In either case, the copying to a mutable string will fix it.

What I think may be happening is that one of your `strtok`s is returning NULL. This would be the case if you're processing a line with less than three fields (e.g., "hello there" where the third `strtok` will return NULL).

Print out the string in your code before the `strtok` calls:

```
std::cerr << "[" << s << "]" << std::endl;
```

(and ensure you free the string after the `strtok` calls lest you end up with a memory leak).

If that turns out to be the problem, the solution depends on what you need. You could ignore those lines totally by checking and copying the individual string out before calling `set...()` - in other words, only call them if all three strings were non-null.

You could check the string before hand to count the number of separators, ensuring that there were at least two.

I'm sure there are other possibilities but I can't really help until:

1. We know that the problem is as suspected; and
2. You tell us what you want to happen.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Many implementations of `std::string` will return a pointer to an empty string literal `""` from `c_str()` when the string is empty. This *is* read-only memory.

Answer (score 0):

`strtok()` will return `NULL` if there are no more tokens left. You have to check for that if you hand that pointer e.g. to the constructor or assignment operator of a `std::string`.

```
char* token = ::strtok(0, " ");
if(!token) {
    // handle error
}
```

Still, consider using string-streams or other more C++-like functionality to avoid falling over such traps in the first place.